# Spring Boot Customizer for Javers

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

We are building a Spring Boot application with a PostgreSQL DB that uses Javers to generate an audit trail of user interactions with the app. We are relying on the auto-detection of Hibernates @Entity which works well for most cases, but for a few exceptions. For these cases we registrate the exceptional classes with `JaversBuilder#registerEntities` (on the advice of the documentation: https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#mapping-configuration).

The problem with that is, that now the auto-configuration of Javers is overridden and thus the spring boot defaults no longer are applied. This results e.g. in a Javers in-memory repository instead of the SQL repository.

Is there a spring boot customizer available or planned that is able to override / set certain values and leaves the rest to spring boot? I thinking of something like [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my question. There is already some kind of customization, called `JaversBuilderPlugin`. To customize the configured spring boot instance of Javers you can provide a `JaversBuilderPlugin` like this:

```
  @Bean
  JaversBuilderPlugin customizeJavers() {
    return javersBuilder -> javersBuilder.registerEntity(ExceptionalClass.class);
  }
```